# Install IBM 5250 Emulator

Tags: debian

I'm needing help installing IBM's 5250 emulator onto the Raspberry Pi. If anyone could take a look at this link and set me in the right direction that would be great! Currently I've installed Raspbian “wheezy” and have everything working. I've followed [This Guys Guide](http://loudifier.com/the-raspberry-pi-is-still-not-going-to-change-the-world/) but this emulator does not support the features that I need.
[Here is a link to IBM's site with files.](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/linux_resources.html)

Comment: It looks like IBM's package is for x86 Linux. Unless it is distributed as source or they have an ARM version you are probably out of luck.

Comment: Thanks Craig. What about running a windows version. Would that be possible?

Comment: Not on a Raspberry Pi. It doesn't run windows (and those window binaries would be for x86 not ARM anyhow).

Answer (score 1):

As quoted from the site that you linked back to...

> download ncurses - extract it, cd to the ncurses directory

```
> ./configure
> make
> sudo make install
```

> download tn5250 , this is V 0.16.5, the latest stable release

```
> ./configure –help (to figure out what switches you need, like ssl)
> ./configure (with the options you want)
> make
> sudo make install
> sudo apt-get install xterm
```

> now, you can see if it is working by entering xt5250 [i.series.ip.address]

And here is a PDF on how to [configure the tn5250](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CH4QFjAH&url=http://www.chowhouse.com/~james/tn5250-HOWTO.pdf&ei=QTT0UOn1EIfWiAKV24GgDg&usg=AFQjCNE0tpWwjvLliLeRuaPs5d5J37LjwQ&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.cGE)

So when you say it doe not support the features you need. What features are you talking about?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the feature I need: http://imgur.com/XfQ0H           Here is a screenshot running on the Pi after following your guide:http://i.imgur.com/KaS4Y.jpg